# Scikit-learn : Exception when calling fit_predict on a PageRank object with a small edge_list

Tags: scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix, pagerank

I'm experiencing a strange exception when calling the fit_predict method on a PageRank object, with data coming from an edge list.

I get the 'TypeError: The input matrix must be in Scipy sparse format or Numpy ndarray format' exception with the following trace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/hkabla/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sknetwork/ranking/base.py", line 37, in fit_predict
    self.fit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hkabla/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sknetwork/ranking/pagerank.py", line 99, in fit
    adjacency, values, self.bipartite = get_adjacency_values(input_matrix, force_bipartite=force_bipartite,
  File "/Users/hkabla/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sknetwork/utils/format.py", line 203, in get_adjacency_values
    input_matrix = check_format(input_matrix)
  File "/Users/hkabla/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sknetwork/utils/check.py", line 130, in check_format
    raise TypeError('The input matrix must be in Scipy sparse format or Numpy ndarray format.')
TypeError: The input matrix must be in Scipy sparse format or Numpy ndarray format.
```

Can you help me find why I get this error ?

Here is my code:

```
import sknetwork as skn
from sknetwork.ranking import PageRank

edges = [(0, 1), (0, 89), (0, 101), (0, 107), (0, 92), (0, 98), (0, 100), (0, 102), (0, 88), (0, 109), (0, 106), (0, 104), (0, 105), (0, 96), (0, 110), (0, 94), (0, 108), (0, 99), (0, 103), (1, 1), (1, 89), (1, 101), (1, 107), (1, 92), (1, 98), (1, 100), (1, 102), (1, 88), (1, 109), (1, 106), (1, 104), (1, 105), (1, 96), (1, 110), (1, 94), (1, 108), (1, 99), (1, 103), (2, 1), (2, 89), (2, 101), (2, 107), (2, 92), (2, 98), (2, 100), (2, 102), (2, 109), (2, 106), (2, 104), (2, 105), (2, 96), (2, 110), (2, 94), (2, 108), (2, 99), (2, 103), (2, 0), (2, 26), (2, 21), (2, 28), (2, 24), (2, 33), (2, 17), (2, 19), (2, 35), (2, 30), (2, 37), (2, 38), (3, 1), (3, 89), (3, 101), (3, 107), (3, 92), (3, 98), (3, 100), (3, 102), (3, 109), (3, 106), (3, 104), (3, 105), (3, 96), (3, 110), (3, 94), (3, 108), (3, 99), (3, 103), (3, 0), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 89), (4, 101), (4, 107), (4, 92), (4, 98), (4, 100), (4, 102), (4, 109), (4, 106), (4, 104), (4, 105), (4, 96), (4, 110), (4, 94), (4, 108), (4, 99), (4, 103), (4, 0), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 2), (4, 3), (5, 1), (5, 89), (5, 101), (5, 107), (5, 92), (5, 98), (5, 100), (5, 102), (5, 109), (5, 106), (5, 104), (5, 105), (5, 96), (5, 110), (5, 94), (5, 108), (5, 99), (5, 103), (5, 0), (5, 9), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 3), (6, 1), (6, 89), (6, 101), (6, 107), (6, 92), (6, 98), (6, 100), (6, 102), (6, 109), (6, 106), (6, 104), (6, 105), (6, 96), (6, 110), (6, 94), (6, 108), (6, 99), (6, 103), (6, 0), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 2), (6, 4), (6, 3), (7, 1), (7, 89), (7, 101), (7, 107), (7, 92), (7, 98), (7, 100), (7, 102), (7, 109), (7, 106), (7, 104), (7, 105), (7, 96), (7, 110), (7, 94), (7, 108), (7, 99), (7, 103), (7, 0), (7, 11), (7, 9), (7, 2), (8, 1), (8, 89), (8, 101), (8, 107), (8, 92), (8, 98), (8, 100), (8, 102), (8, 109), (8, 106), (8, 104), (8, 105), (8, 96), (8, 110), (8, 94), (8, 108), (8, 99), (8, 103), (8, 0), (8, 9), (8, 2), (8, 7), (9, 1), (9, 89), (9, 101), (9, 107), (9, 92), (9, 98), (9, 100), (9, 102), (9, 109), (9, 106), (9, 104), (9, 105), (9, 96), (9, 110), (9, 94), (9, 108), (9, 99), (9, 103), (9, 0), (9, 11), (9, 9), (9, 5), (9, 2), (9, 7), (9, 8), (10, 1), (10, 89), (10, 101), (10, 107), (10, 92), (10, 98), (10, 100), (10, 102), (10, 109), (10, 106), (10, 104), (10, 105), (10, 96), (10, 110), (10, 94), (10, 108), (10, 99), (10, 103), (10, 0), (10, 11), (10, 2), (10, 7), (11, 1), (11, 89), (11, 101), (11, 107), (11, 92), (11, 98), (11, 100), (11, 102), (11, 109), (11, 106), (11, 104), (11, 105), (11, 96), (11, 110), (11, 94), (11, 108), (11, 99), (11, 103), (11, 0), (11, 11), (11, 17), (11, 9), (11, 2), (11, 7), (11, 10), (15, 1), (15, 89), (15, 101), (15, 107), (15, 92), (15, 98), (15, 100), (15, 102), (15, 109), (15, 106), (15, 104), (15, 105), (15, 96), (15, 110), (15, 94), (15, 108), (15, 99), (15, 103), (15, 0), (15, 21), (15, 17), (15, 19), (15, 2), (16, 1), (16, 89), (16, 101), (16, 107), (16, 92), (16, 98), (16, 100), (16, 102), (16, 109), (16, 106), (16, 104), (16, 105), (16, 96), (16, 110), (16, 94), (16, 108), (16, 99), (16, 103), (16, 0), (16, 17), (16, 15), (16, 2), (17, 1), (17, 89), (17, 101), (17, 107), (17, 92), (17, 98), (17, 100), (17, 102), (17, 109), (17, 106), (17, 104), (17, 105), (17, 96), (17, 110), (17, 94), (17, 108), (17, 99), (17, 103), (17, 0), (17, 11), (17, 17), (17, 19), (17, 15), (17, 16), (17, 2), (18, 1), (18, 89), (18, 101), (18, 107), (18, 92), (18, 98), (18, 100), (18, 102), (18, 109), (18, 106), (18, 104), (18, 105), (18, 96), (18, 110), (18, 94), (18, 108), (18, 99), (18, 103), (18, 0), (18, 19), (18, 15), (18, 2), (19, 1), (19, 89), (19, 101), (19, 107), (19, 92), (19, 98), (19, 100), (19, 102), (19, 109), (19, 106), (19, 104), (19, 105), (19, 96), (19, 110), (19, 94), (19, 108), (19, 99), (19, 103), (19, 0), (19, 21), (19, 17), (19, 19), (19, 15), (19, 18), (19, 2), (20, 1), (20, 89), (20, 101), (20, 107), (20, 92), (20, 98), (20, 100), (20, 102), (20, 109), (20, 106), (20, 104), (20, 105), (20, 96), (20, 110), (20, 94), (20, 108), (20, 99), (20, 103), (20, 0), (20, 21), (20, 15), (20, 2), (21, 1), (21, 89), (21, 101), (21, 107), (21, 92), (21, 98), (21, 100), (21, 102), (21, 109), (21, 106), (21, 104), (21, 105), (21, 96), (21, 110), (21, 94), (21, 108), (21, 99), (21, 103), (21, 0), (21, 21), (21, 24), (21, 19), (21, 15), (21, 20), (21, 2), (22, 1), (22, 89), (22, 101), (22, 107), (22, 92), (22, 98), (22, 100), (22, 102), (22, 109), (22, 106), (22, 104), (22, 105), (22, 96), (22, 110), (22, 94), (22, 108), (22, 99), (22, 103), (22, 0), (22, 26), (22, 28), (22, 24), (22, 30), (22, 2), (23, 1), (23, 89), (23, 101), (23, 107), (23, 92), (23, 98), (23, 100), (23, 102), (23, 109), (23, 106), (23, 104), (23, 105), (23, 96), (23, 110), (23, 94), (23, 108), (23, 99), (23, 103), (23, 0), (23, 24), (23, 2), (23, 22), (24, 1), (24, 89), (24, 101), (24, 107), (24, 92), (24, 98), (24, 100), (24, 102), (24, 109), (24, 106), (24, 104), (24, 105), (24, 96), (24, 110), (24, 94), (24, 108), (24, 99), (24, 103), (24, 0), (24, 26), (24, 21), (24, 24), (24, 23), (24, 2), (24, 22), (25, 1), (25, 89), (25, 101), (25, 107), (25, 92), (25, 98), (25, 100), (25, 102), (25, 109), (25, 106), (25, 104), (25, 105), (25, 96), (25, 110), (25, 94), (25, 108), (25, 99), (25, 103), (25, 0), (25, 26), (25, 2), (25, 22), (26, 1), (26, 89), (26, 101), (26, 107), (26, 92), (26, 98), (26, 100), (26, 102), (26, 109), (26, 106), (26, 104), (26, 105), (26, 96), (26, 110), (26, 94), (26, 108), (26, 99), (26, 103), (26, 0), (26, 26), (26, 28), (26, 24), (26, 25), (26, 2), (26, 22), (27, 1), (27, 89), (27, 101), (27, 107), (27, 92), (27, 98), (27, 100), (27, 102), (27, 109), (27, 106), (27, 104), (27, 105), (27, 96), (27, 110), (27, 94), (27, 108), (27, 99), (27, 103), (27, 0), (27, 28), (27, 2), (27, 22), (28, 1), (28, 89), (28, 101), (28, 107), (28, 92), (28, 98), (28, 100), (28, 102), (28, 109), (28, 106), (28, 104), (28, 105), (28, 96), (28, 110), (28, 94), (28, 108), (28, 99), (28, 103), (28, 0), (28, 26), (28, 28), (28, 30), (28, 27), (28, 2), (28, 22), (29, 1), (29, 89), (29, 101), (29, 107), (29, 92), (29, 98), (29, 100), (29, 102), (29, 109), (29, 106), (29, 104), (29, 105), (29, 96), (29, 110), (29, 94), (29, 108), (29, 99), (29, 103), (29, 0), (29, 30), (29, 2), (29, 22), (30, 1), (30, 89), (30, 101), (30, 107), (30, 92), (30, 98), (30, 100), (30, 102), (30, 109), (30, 106), (30, 104), (30, 105), (30, 96), (30, 110), (30, 94), (30, 108), (30, 99), (30, 103), (30, 0), (30, 28), (30, 33), (30, 30), (30, 29), (30, 2), (30, 22), (31, 1), (31, 89), (31, 101), (31, 107), (31, 92), (31, 98), (31, 100), (31, 102), (31, 109), (31, 106), (31, 104), (31, 105), (31, 96), (31, 110), (31, 94), (31, 108), (31, 99), (31, 103), (31, 0), (31, 33), (31, 35), (31, 37), (31, 2), (32, 1), (32, 89), (32, 101), (32, 107), (32, 92), (32, 98), (32, 100), (32, 102), (32, 109), (32, 106), (32, 104), (32, 105), (32, 96), (32, 110), (32, 94), (32, 108), (32, 99), (32, 103), (32, 0), (32, 33), (32, 31), (32, 2), (33, 1), (33, 89), (33, 101), (33, 107), (33, 92), (33, 98), (33, 100), (33, 102), (33, 109), (33, 106), (33, 104), (33, 105), (33, 96), (33, 110), (33, 94), (33, 108), (33, 99), (33, 103), (33, 0), (33, 33), (33, 35), (33, 30), (33, 31), (33, 2), (33, 32), (34, 1), (34, 89), (34, 101), (34, 107), (34, 92), (34, 98), (34, 100), (34, 102), (34, 109), (34, 106), (34, 104), (34, 105), (34, 96), (34, 110), (34, 94), (34, 108), (34, 99), (34, 103), (34, 0), (34, 35), (34, 31), (34, 2), (35, 1), (35, 89), (35, 101), (35, 107), (35, 92), (35, 98), (35, 100), (35, 102), (35, 109), (35, 106), (35, 104), (35, 105), (35, 96), (35, 110), (35, 94), (35, 108), (35, 99), (35, 103), (35, 0), (35, 33), (35, 35), (35, 37), (35, 31), (35, 34), (35, 2), (36, 1), (36, 89), (36, 101), (36, 107), (36, 92), (36, 98), (36, 100), (36, 102), (36, 109), (36, 106), (36, 104), (36, 105), (36, 96), (36, 110), (36, 94), (36, 108), (36, 99), (36, 103), (36, 0), (36, 37), (36, 31), (36, 2), (37, 1), (37, 89), (37, 101), (37, 107), (37, 92), (37, 98), (37, 100), (37, 102), (37, 109), (37, 106), (37, 104), (37, 105), (37, 96), (37, 110), (37, 94), (37, 108), (37, 99), (37, 103), (37, 0), (37, 35), (37, 42), (37, 37), (37, 36), (37, 31), (37, 2), (38, 1), (38, 89), (38, 101), (38, 107), (38, 92), (38, 98), (38, 100), (38, 102), (38, 109), (38, 106), (38, 104), (38, 105), (38, 96), (38, 110), (38, 94), (38, 108), (38, 99), (38, 103), (38, 0), (38, 11), (38, 9), (38, 5), (38, 6), (38, 2), (39, 1), (39, 89), (39, 101), (39, 107), (39, 92), (39, 98), (39, 100), (39, 102), (39, 109), (39, 106), (39, 104), (39, 105), (39, 96), (39, 110), (39, 94), (39, 108), (39, 99), (39, 103), (39, 0), (39, 48), (39, 42), (39, 45), (40, 1), (40, 89), (40, 101), (40, 107), (40, 92), (40, 98), (40, 100), (40, 102), (40, 109), (40, 106), (40, 104), (40, 105), (40, 96), (40, 110), (40, 94), (40, 108), (40, 103), (40, 99), (40, 0), (40, 42), (40, 39), (41, 1), (41, 89), (41, 101), (41, 92), (41, 107), (41, 98), (41, 100), (41, 102), (41, 109), (41, 106), (41, 104), (41, 105), (41, 96), (41, 110), (41, 94), (41, 108), (41, 99), (41, 103), (41, 0), (41, 42), (41, 39), (41, 40), (42, 1), (42, 89), (42, 101), (42, 107), (42, 92), (42, 98), (42, 100), (42, 102), (42, 109), (42, 106), (42, 104), (42, 105), (42, 96), (42, 110), (42, 94), (42, 108), (42, 99), (42, 103), (42, 0), (42, 42), (42, 37), (42, 39), (42, 45), (42, 40), (42, 41), (43, 1), (43, 89), (43, 101), (43, 107), (43, 92), (43, 98), (43, 100), (43, 102), (43, 109), (43, 106), (43, 104), (43, 105), (43, 96), (43, 110), (43, 94), (43, 108), (43, 99), (43, 103), (43, 0), (43, 39), (43, 45), (44, 1), (44, 89), (44, 101), (44, 107), (44, 92), (44, 98), (44, 100), (44, 102), (44, 109), (44, 106), (44, 104), (44, 105), (44, 96), (44, 110), (44, 94), (44, 108), (44, 99), (44, 103), (44, 0), (44, 39), (44, 45), (44, 43), (45, 1), (45, 89), (45, 101), (45, 107), (45, 92), (45, 98), (45, 100), (45, 102), (45, 109), (45, 106), (45, 104), (45, 105), (45, 96), (45, 110), (45, 94), (45, 108), (45, 99), (45, 103), (45, 0), (45, 48), (45, 42), (45, 39), (45, 45), (45, 44), (45, 43), (46, 1), (46, 89), (46, 101), (46, 107), (46, 92), (46, 98), (46, 96), (46, 100), (46, 102), (46, 109), (46, 106), (46, 104), (46, 105), (46, 110), (46, 94), (46, 108), (46, 99), (46, 103), (46, 0), (46, 48), (46, 39), (47, 1), (47, 89), (47, 101), (47, 107), (47, 92), (47, 98), (47, 100), (47, 102), (47, 109), (47, 106), (47, 104), (47, 105), (47, 96), (47, 110), (47, 94), (47, 108), (47, 99), (47, 103), (47, 0), (47, 48), (47, 46), (47, 39), (48, 1), (48, 89), (48, 101), (48, 107), (48, 92), (48, 98), (48, 100), (48, 102), (48, 109), (48, 106), (48, 104), (48, 105), (48, 96), (48, 110), (48, 94), (48, 108), (48, 99), (48, 103), (48, 0), (48, 74), (48, 48), (48, 52), (48, 46), (48, 39), (48, 45), (48, 47), (49, 1), (49, 89), (49, 101), (49, 107), (49, 92), (49, 98), (49, 100), (49, 102), (49, 109), (49, 106), (49, 104), (49, 105), (49, 96), (49, 110), (49, 94), (49, 108), (49, 99), (49, 103), (49, 0), (49, 57), (49, 55), (49, 52), (50, 1), (50, 89), (50, 101), (50, 107), (50, 92), (50, 98), (50, 100), (50, 102), (50, 109), (50, 106), (50, 104), (50, 105), (50, 96), (50, 110), (50, 94), (50, 108), (50, 99), (50, 103), (50, 0), (50, 52), (50, 49), (51, 1), (51, 89), (51, 101), (51, 107), (51, 92), (51, 98), (51, 100), (51, 102), (51, 109), (51, 106), (51, 108), (51, 104), (51, 105), (51, 96), (51, 110), (51, 94), (51, 99), (51, 103), (51, 0), (51, 52), (51, 49), (51, 50), (52, 1), (52, 89), (52, 101), (52, 107), (52, 92), (52, 98), (52, 100), (52, 102), (52, 109), (52, 106), (52, 104), (52, 105), (52, 96), (52, 110), (52, 94), (52, 108), (52, 99), (52, 103), (52, 0), (52, 48), (52, 55), (52, 52), (52, 49), (52, 50), (52, 51), (53, 1), (53, 89), (53, 101), (53, 107), (53, 92), (53, 98), (53, 100), (53, 102), (53, 109), (53, 106), (53, 104), (53, 105), (53, 96), (53, 110), (53, 94), (53, 108), (53, 99), (53, 103), (53, 0), (53, 57), (53, 55), (53, 49), (54, 1), (54, 89), (54, 101), (54, 107), (54, 92), (54, 98), (54, 100), (54, 102), (54, 109), (54, 106), (54, 104), (54, 105), (54, 96), (54, 110), (54, 94), (54, 108), (54, 99), (54, 103), (54, 0), (54, 55), (54, 53), (54, 49), (55, 1), (55, 89), (55, 101), (55, 107), (55, 92), (55, 98), (55, 100), (55, 102), (55, 109), (55, 106), (55, 104), (55, 105), (55, 96), (55, 110), (55, 94), (55, 108), (55, 99), (55, 103), (55, 0), (55, 57), (55, 55), (55, 52), (55, 54), (55, 53), (55, 49), (56, 1), (56, 89), (56, 101), (56, 107), (56, 92), (56, 98), (56, 100), (56, 102), (56, 109), (56, 106), (56, 104), (56, 105), (56, 96), (56, 110), (56, 94), (56, 108), (56, 99), (56, 103), (56, 0), (56, 57), (56, 53), (56, 49), (57, 1), (57, 89), (57, 101), (57, 107), (57, 92), (57, 98), (57, 100), (57, 102), (57, 109), (57, 106), (57, 104), (57, 105), (57, 96), (57, 110), (57, 94), (57, 108), (57, 99), (57, 103), (57, 0), (57, 57), (57, 55), (57, 61), (57, 53), (57, 49), (57, 56), (59, 1), (59, 89), (59, 101), (59, 107), (59, 92), (59, 98), (59, 100), (59, 102), (59, 109), (59, 106), (59, 104), (59, 105), (59, 96), (59, 110), (59, 94), (59, 108), (59, 99), (59, 103), (59, 0), (59, 63), (59, 61), (59, 58), (60, 1), (60, 89), (60, 101), (60, 107), (60, 92), (60, 98), (60, 100), (60, 102), (60, 109), (60, 106), (60, 104), (60, 105), (60, 96), (60, 110), (60, 94), (60, 108), (60, 99), (60, 103), (60, 0), (60, 61), (60, 59), (60, 58), (61, 1), (61, 89), (61, 101), (61, 107), (61, 92), (61, 98), (61, 100), (61, 102), (61, 109), (61, 106), (61, 104), (61, 105), (61, 96), (61, 110), (61, 94), (61, 108), (61, 99), (61, 103), (61, 0), (61, 57), (61, 63), (61, 61), (61, 60), (61, 59), (61, 58), (62, 1), (62, 89), (62, 101), (62, 107), (62, 92), (62, 98), (62, 100), (62, 102), (62, 109), (62, 106), (62, 104), (62, 105), (62, 96), (62, 110), (62, 94), (62, 108), (62, 99), (62, 103), (62, 0), (62, 63), (62, 59), (62, 58), (63, 1), (63, 89), (63, 101), (63, 107), (63, 92), (63, 98), (63, 100), (63, 102), (63, 109), (63, 106), (63, 104), (63, 105), (63, 96), (63, 110), (63, 94), (63, 108), (63, 99), (63, 103), (63, 66), (63, 0), (63, 63), (63, 61), (63, 62), (63, 59), (63, 58), (64, 1), (64, 89), (64, 101), (64, 107), (64, 92), (64, 98), (64, 100), (64, 102), (64, 109), (64, 106), (64, 104), (64, 105), (64, 96), (64, 110), (64, 94), (64, 108), (64, 99), (64, 103), (64, 66), (64, 68), (64, 0), (64, 58), (65, 1), (65, 89), (65, 101), (65, 107), (65, 92), (65, 98), (65, 100), (65, 102), (65, 109), (65, 106), (65, 104), (65, 105), (65, 96), (65, 110), (65, 94), (65, 108), (65, 99), (65, 103), (65, 66), (65, 0), (65, 64), (65, 58), (66, 1), (66, 89), (66, 101), (66, 107), (66, 92), (66, 98), (66, 100), (66, 102), (66, 109), (66, 106), (66, 104), (66, 105), (66, 96), (66, 110), (66, 94), (66, 108), (66, 99), (66, 103), (66, 66), (66, 68), (66, 0), (66, 63), (66, 65), (66, 64), (66, 58), (67, 1), (67, 89), (67, 101), (67, 107), (67, 92), (67, 98), (67, 100), (67, 102), (67, 109), (67, 106), (67, 104), (67, 105), (67, 96), (67, 110), (67, 94), (67, 108), (67, 99), (67, 103), (67, 68), (67, 0), (67, 64), (67, 58), (68, 1), (68, 89), (68, 101), (68, 107), (68, 92), (68, 98), (68, 100), (68, 102), (68, 109), (68, 106), (68, 104), (68, 105), (68, 96), (68, 110), (68, 94), (68, 108), (68, 99), (68, 103), (68, 66), (68, 68), (68, 0), (68, 71), (68, 64), (68, 67), (68, 58), (69, 1), (69, 89), (69, 101), (69, 107), (69, 92), (69, 98), (69, 100), (69, 102), (69, 109), (69, 106), (69, 104), (69, 105), (69, 96), (69, 110), (69, 94), (69, 108), (69, 99), (69, 103), (69, 0), (69, 71), (69, 58), (70, 1), (70, 89), (70, 101), (70, 107), (70, 92), (70, 98), (70, 100), (70, 102), (70, 109), (70, 106), (70, 104), (70, 105), (70, 96), (70, 110), (70, 94), (70, 108), (70, 99), (70, 103), (70, 0), (70, 71), (70, 69), (70, 58), (71, 1), (71, 89), (71, 101), (71, 107), (71, 92), (71, 98), (71, 100), (71, 102), (71, 109), (71, 106), (71, 104), (71, 105), (71, 96), (71, 110), (71, 94), (71, 108), (71, 99), (71, 103), (71, 68), (71, 0), (71, 71), (71, 74), (71, 70), (71, 112), (71, 69), (71, 111), (71, 58), (72, 1), (72, 89), (72, 101), (72, 107), (72, 92), (72, 98), (72, 100), (72, 102), (72, 109), (72, 106), (72, 104), (72, 105), (72, 96), (72, 110), (72, 94), (72, 108), (72, 99), (72, 103), (72, 0), (72, 74), (72, 58), (73, 1), (73, 89), (73, 101), (73, 107), (73, 92), (73, 98), (73, 100), (73, 102), (73, 109), (73, 106), (73, 104), (73, 105), (73, 96), (73, 110), (73, 94), (73, 108), (73, 99), (73, 103), (73, 0), (73, 74), (73, 72), (73, 58), (74, 1), (74, 89), (74, 101), (74, 107), (74, 92), (74, 98), (74, 100), (74, 102), (74, 109), (74, 106), (74, 104), (74, 105), (74, 96), (74, 110), (74, 94), (74, 108), (74, 99), (74, 103), (74, 0), (74, 71), (74, 74), (74, 48), (74, 81), (74, 73), (74, 72), (74, 58), (78, 1), (78, 89), (78, 101), (78, 107), (78, 92), (78, 98), (78, 100), (78, 102), (78, 109), (78, 106), (78, 104), (78, 105), (78, 96), (78, 110), (78, 94), (78, 108), (78, 99), (78, 103), (78, 0), (78, 81), (78, 84), (79, 1), (79, 89), (79, 101), (79, 107), (79, 92), (79, 98), (79, 100), (79, 102), (79, 109), (79, 106), (79, 104), (79, 105), (79, 96), (79, 110), (79, 94), (79, 108), (79, 99), (79, 103), (79, 0), (79, 81), (79, 78), (80, 1), (80, 89), (80, 101), (80, 107), (80, 92), (80, 98), (80, 100), (80, 102), (80, 109), (80, 106), (80, 104), (80, 105), (80, 96), (80, 110), (80, 94), (80, 108), (80, 99), (80, 103), (80, 0), (80, 81), (80, 79), (80, 78), (81, 1), (81, 89), (81, 101), (81, 107), (81, 92), (81, 98), (81, 100), (81, 102), (81, 109), (81, 106), (81, 104), (81, 105), (81, 96), (81, 110), (81, 94), (81, 108), (81, 99), (81, 103), (81, 0), (81, 74), (81, 81), (81, 84), (81, 80), (81, 113), (81, 79), (81, 78), (82, 1), (82, 89), (82, 101), (82, 107), (82, 92), (82, 98), (82, 100), (82, 102), (82, 109), (82, 106), (82, 104), (82, 105), (82, 96), (82, 110), (82, 94), (82, 108), (82, 99), (82, 103), (82, 0), (82, 84), (82, 78), (83, 1), (83, 89), (83, 101), (83, 107), (83, 92), (83, 98), (83, 100), (83, 102), (83, 109), (83, 106), (83, 104), (83, 105), (83, 96), (83, 110), (83, 94), (83, 108), (83, 99), (83, 103), (83, 0), (83, 84), (83, 82), (83, 78), (84, 1), (84, 89), (84, 101), (84, 107), (84, 92), (84, 98), (84, 100), (84, 102), (84, 88), (84, 109), (84, 106), (84, 104), (84, 105), (84, 96), (84, 110), (84, 94), (84, 108), (84, 99), (84, 103), (84, 0), (84, 81), (84, 84), (84, 82), (84, 83), (84, 78), (85, 1), (85, 89), (85, 101), (85, 107), (85, 92), (85, 98), (85, 100), (85, 102), (85, 88), (85, 109), (85, 106), (85, 104), (85, 105), (85, 96), (85, 110), (85, 94), (85, 108), (85, 99), (85, 103), (85, 0), (86, 1), (86, 89), (86, 101), (86, 107), (86, 92), (86, 98), (86, 100), (86, 102), (86, 88), (86, 109), (86, 106), (86, 104), (86, 105), (86, 96), (86, 110), (86, 94), (86, 108), (86, 99), (86, 103), (86, 85), (86, 0), (87, 1), (87, 89), (87, 101), (87, 107), (87, 92), (87, 98), (87, 100), (87, 102), (87, 88), (87, 109), (87, 106), (87, 104), (87, 105), (87, 96), (87, 110), (87, 94), (87, 108), (87, 99), (87, 103), (87, 85), (87, 0), (87, 86), (88, 1), (88, 89), (88, 101), (88, 107), (88, 92), (88, 98), (88, 100), (88, 102), (88, 88), (88, 109), (88, 106), (88, 104), (88, 105), (88, 96), (88, 110), (88, 94), (88, 108), (88, 99), (88, 103), (88, 87), (88, 85), (88, 0), (88, 86), (88, 84), (89, 1), (89, 89), (89, 101), (89, 107), (89, 92), (89, 98), (89, 100), (89, 102), (89, 88), (89, 109), (89, 106), (89, 104), (89, 105), (89, 96), (89, 110), (89, 94), (89, 108), (89, 99), (89, 103), (89, 66), (89, 68), (89, 0), (89, 57), (89, 71), (89, 74), (89, 90), (89, 63), (89, 81), (89, 84), (89, 61), (90, 1), (90, 89), (90, 101), (90, 107), (90, 92), (90, 98), (90, 100), (90, 102), (90, 109), (90, 106), (90, 104), (90, 105), (90, 96), (90, 110), (90, 94), (90, 108), (90, 99), (90, 103), (90, 0), (90, 48), (90, 55), (90, 28), (90, 33), (90, 35), (90, 42), (90, 52), (90, 30), (90, 37), (90, 45), (90, 91), (91, 1), (91, 89), (91, 101), (91, 107), (91, 92), (91, 98), (91, 100), (91, 102), (91, 109), (91, 106), (91, 104), (91, 105), (91, 96), (91, 110), (91, 94), (91, 108), (91, 99), (91, 103), (91, 0), (91, 26), (91, 21), (91, 90), (91, 11), (91, 24), (91, 17), (91, 19), (91, 9), (91, 5), (91, 6), (92, 1), (92, 89), (92, 101), (92, 107), (92, 92), (92, 98), (92, 100), (92, 102), (92, 109), (92, 106), (92, 104), (92, 105), (92, 96), (92, 110), (92, 94), (92, 108), (92, 99), (92, 103), (92, 0), (92, 26), (92, 21), (92, 28), (92, 11), (92, 24), (92, 17), (92, 19), (92, 35), (92, 30), (92, 37), (92, 93), (93, 1), (93, 89), (93, 101), (93, 107), (93, 92), (93, 98), (93, 100), (93, 102), (93, 109), (93, 106), (93, 104), (93, 105), (93, 96), (93, 110), (93, 94), (93, 108), (93, 99), (93, 103), (93, 0), (93, 9), (93, 5), (94, 1), (94, 89), (94, 101), (94, 107), (94, 92), (94, 98), (94, 100), (94, 102), (94, 109), (94, 106), (94, 104), (94, 105), (94, 96), (94, 110), (94, 94), (94, 108), (94, 99), (94, 103), (94, 66), (94, 68), (94, 0), (94, 95), (94, 57), (94, 71), (94, 74), (94, 48), (94, 55), (94, 52), (94, 84), (94, 61), (95, 1), (95, 89), (95, 101), (95, 107), (95, 92), (95, 98), (95, 100), (95, 102), (95, 109), (95, 106), (95, 104), (95, 105), (95, 96), (95, 110), (95, 94), (95, 108), (95, 99), (95, 103), (95, 0), (95, 45), (95, 6), (96, 1), (96, 89), (96, 101), (96, 107), (96, 92), (96, 98), (96, 100), (96, 102), (96, 109), (96, 106), (96, 104), (96, 105), (96, 96), (96, 110), (96, 94), (96, 108), (96, 99), (96, 103), (96, 0), (96, 33), (96, 63), (96, 81), (96, 42), (97, 1), (97, 89), (97, 101), (97, 107), (97, 92), (97, 98), (97, 100), (97, 102), (97, 109), (97, 106), (97, 104), (97, 105), (97, 96), (97, 110), (97, 94), (97, 108), (97, 99), (97, 103), (97, 0), (98, 1), (98, 89), (98, 101), (98, 107), (98, 92), (98, 98), (98, 100), (98, 102), (98, 109), (98, 106), (98, 104), (98, 105), (98, 96), (98, 110), (98, 94), (98, 108), (98, 99), (98, 103), (98, 0), (99, 1), (99, 89), (99, 101), (99, 107), (99, 92), (99, 98), (99, 100), (99, 102), (99, 109), (99, 106), (99, 104), (99, 105), (99, 96), (99, 110), (99, 94), (99, 108), (99, 99), (99, 103), (99, 0), (100, 1), (100, 89), (100, 101), (100, 107), (100, 92), (100, 98), (100, 100), (100, 102), (100, 109), (100, 106), (100, 104), (100, 105), (100, 96), (100, 110), (100, 94), (100, 108), (100, 99), (100, 103), (100, 0), (100, 114), (100, 97), (101, 1), (101, 89), (101, 101), (101, 107), (101, 92), (101, 98), (101, 100), (101, 102), (101, 109), (101, 106), (101, 104), (101, 105), (101, 96), (101, 110), (101, 94), (101, 108), (101, 99), (101, 103), (101, 0), (102, 1), (102, 89), (102, 101), (102, 107), (102, 92), (102, 98), (102, 100), (102, 102), (102, 109), (102, 106), (102, 104), (102, 105), (102, 96), (102, 110), (102, 94), (102, 108), (102, 99), (102, 103), (102, 0), (103, 1), (103, 89), (103, 101), (103, 107), (103, 92), (103, 98), (103, 100), (103, 102), (103, 109), (103, 106), (103, 104), (103, 105), (103, 96), (103, 110), (103, 94), (103, 108), (103, 99), (103, 103), (103, 0), (104, 1), (104, 89), (104, 101), (104, 107), (104, 92), (104, 98), (104, 100), (104, 102), (104, 109), (104, 106), (104, 104), (104, 105), (104, 96), (104, 110), (104, 94), (104, 108), (104, 99), (104, 103), (104, 0), (105, 1), (105, 89), (105, 101), (105, 107), (105, 92), (105, 98), (105, 100), (105, 102), (105, 109), (105, 106), (105, 104), (105, 105), (105, 96), (105, 110), (105, 94), (105, 108), (105, 99), (105, 103), (105, 0), (106, 1), (106, 89), (106, 101), (106, 107), (106, 92), (106, 98), (106, 100), (106, 102), (106, 109), (106, 106), (106, 104), (106, 105), (106, 96), (106, 110), (106, 94), (106, 108), (106, 99), (106, 103), (106, 0), (107, 1), (107, 89), (107, 101), (107, 107), (107, 92), (107, 98), (107, 100), (107, 102), (107, 109), (107, 106), (107, 104), (107, 105), (107, 96), (107, 110), (107, 94), (107, 108), (107, 99), (107, 103), (107, 0), (108, 1), (108, 89), (108, 101), (108, 107), (108, 92), (108, 98), (108, 100), (108, 102), (108, 109), (108, 106), (108, 104), (108, 105), (108, 96), (108, 110), (108, 94), (108, 108), (108, 99), (108, 103), (108, 0), (109, 1), (109, 89), (109, 101), (109, 107), (109, 92), (109, 98), (109, 100), (109, 102), (109, 109), (109, 106), (109, 104), (109, 105), (109, 96), (109, 110), (109, 94), (109, 108), (109, 99), (109, 103), (109, 0), (110, 1), (110, 89), (110, 101), (110, 107), (110, 92), (110, 98), (110, 100), (110, 102), (110, 109), (110, 106), (110, 104), (110, 105), (110, 96), (110, 110), (110, 94), (110, 108), (110, 99), (110, 103), (110, 0), (110, 48)]

adjacency = skn.data.from_edge_list(edges)
pagerank = PageRank()
pagerank.fit_predict(adjacency)
```

The adjacency object did not seem to be very large :

```
>>> adjacency
{'names': array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  15,
        16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,
        29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,
        42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,
        55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,
        68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,
        84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,
        97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
       110, 111, 112, 113, 114]), 'adjacency': <109x109 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4063 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding matrix_only=True parameter solved the issue